# Data entry using a combobox displaying values from a related table

Tags: ms-access, combobox, data-entry, ms-access-forms

I'm new to ms access and have started a little project to learn how it works. It's a small database that stores safety datasheets and other documents for a number of chemical substances.

An overview of the relationships:
[DB-Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbIHE.png)

I have made a data entry form that enables users to enter new records (new files + file info):

[DataEntryForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6pic.png)

The form works fine, but currently the user has to manually enter the primary key value (sprache_id) for the language table 'sprachen_tabelle' as a numerical value, which is not great. I would like to change this to a combobox where the user selects the language shorthandle (EN,DE,FR etc.) that is stored in 'sprachen_tabelle' under 'bezeichnung' from the combobox, and the corresponding sprache_id is then automatically applied to the data entry. I would probably hide the id from the user then somehow.

Now, I have tried adding a combobox myself but I ran into the problem that 'sprache_id' is not being updated based on the value selected in the combobox for 'bezeichnung'. One way around works fine, meaning 1: enter sprache_id 2: bezeichnung corresponding to sprache_id is applied automatically. The other way however, does not. When selecting a value with the language shorthandle from the combobox, instead of selecting the record that corresponds to that value in 'sprachen_tabelle' and matching 'sprache_id' to the table 'sdb_tabelle', it seemingly commits to an entirely new record in 'sprachen_tabelle' instead.

Combobox details:

control (Steuerelementinhalt in DE, not sure in english, first row in data):

```
bezeichnung
```

Recordsouce:

```
SELECT [sprachen_tabelle].[bezeichnung] FROM sprachen_tabelle;
```

I have also tried setting the recordsource to:

```
SELECT [sprachen_tabelle].[sprache_id], [sprachen_tabelle].[bezeichnung]  FROM sprachen_tabelle;
```

and the control to:

```
sprache_id
```

but that didn't help either.

Maybe this is a problem because the form is set to data entry, and perhaps i should add a subform to it with data entry off that contains the combobox, but I'm not sure if that would even work. It might also be how the data entry form is set up. It is currently a form that contains the stoff_id  which then has a subform on it for data entry that is linked to 'stoff_id' on the main form:

[Dataentrysubform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBaxQ.png)

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and would really appreciate it if someone could help.
Also, I am aware the names for my forms and fields are a mess right now and that I should probably  just link the files to the database instead of using the attachment feature in access (wanted to try it out though).

Comment: the combo box control source needs to be bound to sprache.id not bezeichnung.  Then to display the bezeichnung instead of the sprache.id set the combobox rowsource to the sprachen.tabelle.  under the combobox settings set the bound column to the sprache.id(usually1) set columns to 2, set column widths to 0,1.  This is basic so just look up Access and combobox.  Again, the control source(bound column) is sprache.id and the row source is 2 columns.  with sprachen.id width set to 0 and bezeichnung set to 1

Comment: Thx, that worked! I knew it was probably something basic.

Comment: Is there some way to change the value being displayed to the language handle instead of the id? I can now select bezeichnung from the combobox and the correct sprache_id shows up once selected but I'd rather have the numerical value completely hidden from the user instead, and just show bezeichnung. That's why i tried using the combobox with bezeichnung as the control source first. Thx again.

Comment: anywhere you see the sprache_id you can show the bezeichnung instead by replacing the textbox with a combobox including the table.  However, best practice is to leave the table alone(avoids confusion).  Instead show the table to the user in a form( usually set the default form view to continous forms in this case)  Then use a combobox to show bezeichnung instead of sprache.id everywhere.  In other words look up Access, continuous forms.  use a continuous form to display the data.  replace (right click) the textbox linked to sprache.id with a combobox that displays the bezeichnung.

Comment: ok, seems what I was referring to was a bug. I had already done what you suggested, the data entry was on a continuous form already and I had changed the sprachen_id textbox to a combobox and went along with your prior instructions. For some reason, on the dropdown menu, it showed a list of "bezeichnung", but when clicking on one, the value that was then displayed by the SAME combobox after selection was the value for sprachen_id.  I selected, say EN, in the combobox and it would then show the value "1" in the same combobox. After restarting access the combobox now works as intended.